# Pass value to scss class from HTML

Tags: html, css, sass

I want a generic class in my scss file which sets the color and border property if i just pass a color value. I dont want to hard code color value in my scss file.

```
@mixin myStyle($color) {
  color: $color;
  border-left: 5px solid $color;
}
.item{
 @include myStyle(red); // i want to pass color value from my html class.
}
```

How to pass arguments from html class name ?

Answer (score 8):

I've create a JSFiddle for you: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/hmr0hckf/3/)

HTML:

```
<p class="item" data-test="red">Vikramaditya</p>
```

SCSS:

```
p::before {
  content: attr(data-test) " ";
}
```

please note: 
The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental.

source: [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Comment: How to pass the color from <p> tag class ? can you pass any color value from classname ?

Comment: I've updated the solution, seems that currently properties other than content are experimental.

Comment: this is awesome!! Worked perfect and is exactly what I need